# Linking Foursquare and Facebook accounts programmatically?

Tags: foursquare, facebook-timeline

I am working on iOS / php / MySQL application, which uses Foursquare API, in order to post check-ins to Foursquare. I would also like to post these Foursquare check-ins to Facebook Timeline map. Is there a way to programmatically connect user's Facebook account with their Foursquare account, and grant them Foursquare permission to post to Facebook wall? I want to do it on the Settings page of my app.

Answer (score 0):

The user will need to grant Foursquare access to their Facebook account, which only the user can do. You can link the user to [their settings page](https://foursquare.com/settings/sharing) where they can elect to connect Facebook to their Foursquare account.